# How to write javascript codes to update local storage data

Tags: javascript

I am working on a edit profile page. the page would show data which the user entered when they first signed up for the account. When they change their display name and password, i would like to save it such that it gets updated into the local storage as well.

What the current local storage shows:

```
{"username":"staff3","name":"alice","password":"123"}
```

For example the user changes the name to ben and password to 1234, the local storage should be

```
{"username":"staff3","name":"ben","password":"1234"}
```

How do I write the codes to make this kind of changes? 
Please don't give comments like 'saving password is a bad idea' as the answer i am doing this for a school project.

In addition I would also like to display user info in another page called profile page, the info would be the one saved in local storage, and I am want to display them as a profile page info. How to I write the codes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802777/how-to-i-write-the-javascript-codes-to-save-and-update-changes-of-data-in-local

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help it but "it's a very bad idea to store passwords in local storage". To answer your question: "How do I write the codes to make this kind of changes?", please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Warning 1** - `localStorage` is not supported in all browsers. [Check browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility).

**Warning 2** - Do not use snippet in production. This is just for demonstration purposes, to show how things work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="profile_details">
<p>Username:    <input type="text" name="username">
<p>Name:    <input type="text" name="name"> <label>New name: </label><label id="new_name"></label>
<p>Password:    <input type="password" name="password"> <label>New password: </label><label id="new_pwd"></label>
<p><input id="sbmtbtn" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var userDb = localStorage;
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector("[name=username]").value = userDb.getItem("username") || "alice";
    document.querySelector("[name=name]").value = userDb.getItem("name") || "Alice" ;
    document.querySelector("[name=password]").value = userDb.getItem("password") || "qwerty";   
}

document.getElementById("sbmtbtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var name = document.querySelector("[name=name]").value;
    var password = document.querySelector("[name=password]").value;
    document.getElementById("new_name").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("new_pwd").innerHTML = password.slice(0,1)+"....";  
    userDb.setItem("name", name);
    userDb.setItem("password", password);   
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use mysql. Using Mysql, you can easily manipulate big(and little) chunks of data. If you would still want to do this over a file, i would suggest saving the array you create to the text file. In case you want to change something, you can read the file, use JSON.parse on the result and bam, you have an array to loop through, find the correct subarray and change the value. Then you simply delete the file and create a new one with your changed array written in it

Now let me explain how you can accomplish said things:

First of all, you want to check if there already is a file created so we can get the contents. In order to do so, you want use PHP:

```
<?php
$filename = 'file.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $fc = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
}else{
    $fc = "none";
}
?>
```

this code will search for a file in the same folder your website.php is located in named *file.txt*. If it finds the file, it will get the content for use to use later on

To get this information to javascript, we simply use this line

```
var filecontent = <?php echo json_encode($fc); ?>;
```

now that we have the variable in javascript, we can modify the information, which we wil do now.

First, we create an array with the text file and append our new data to that array

```
if(contentarray!="none"){
    var contentarray = JSON.parse(filecontent);
    contentarray.push(newentry);
}else{
    contentarray[0] = newentry;
}
```

Our newentry we are talking about here should look something like this

```
var newentry = {"username":"staff3","name":"alice","password":"123"};
```

Now, that we have the updated array, we write to the file using jquery.
First of all, you need to include jquery to your website. In order to do so, you add this line into the (preferably) header of the page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To write to the file, we will at this to our javascript

```
   var text = JSON.stringify(contentarray); 
   $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { data: text },
      success: function(result){
         if(result==1){
             alert("It worked!");
         }else{
             alert("It did not work!");
             console.log(result);
         }
       }
    });
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to create a new file called *script.php*

This is how the script.php should look

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $filename = 'file.txt'; //you want to use the same filename as above
    @unlink($filename); //using the @ to not get an error if there is no file to delete, will be important later
    $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $_POST['data']);
    fclose($myfile);
    echo '1';
}
```

If I missed anything or it gives you errors just say it, i kinda wrote this in a hurry :)

Comment: I have never used mysql before is it part of javascript?

Comment: While I agree that using MySQL is probably the way to go, this doesn't answer or even relate to the question asked by the OP.

Comment: Mysql is a seperate system, used to manage databases. In your case, since this is a school project and not some commercial website, you should still be able use a javascript file without worry

Comment: Oh thanks soo much, BUT im so sorry i have no idea what I'm reading about :( if you don't mind.... can I add u on skype or sth then i share my screen with you?

Comment: Sure thing, send me a message on [twitter](https://twitter.com/pauritt) an i'll be happy to help. Also, please tell me your twitter username so i know i'll be talking to the right person